# jButtons doesn't add correctly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, grid-layout

For better reference I'm doing match3 (candy crush type) game.

```
public class BoardGraphics extends JPanel {
public static final int WIDTH = 400;
public static final int HEIGHT = 400;
private static final Color COLOR = new Color(0xFF0000); //0xF1E4CB

private final Board board;

public BoardGraphics(Board board){
    this.setBackground( COLOR );
    this.setSize(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(board.getHeight(), board.getWidth(), 0, 0));
    this.board = board;
    setVisible(true);
    drawElements();
}
    private void drawElements(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            Point p = new Point(i, j);
            //Point p = new Point(1, 2);

            ImageIcon icon = null;
            try {
                BufferedImage img = null;
                img = ImageIO.read(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/assets/img/gem_" + board.getElement(p).getTileColor().toString() + ".gif"));

                icon = new ImageIcon(img);

                JButton btn = new JButton(icon);
                btn.setVisible(true);
                btn.setOpaque(false);
                btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                btn.setBorderPainted(false);
                btn.setSize(50, 50);
                if (i == 1) {
                    btn.setLocation(100, 100); // <- i did this for testing. with this i see 2 gems
                }
                this.add(btn);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        }
    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();
    }
}
```

and jFrame code here:

```
public class GameGraphics extends JFrame {
private final int WIDTH = 600;
private final int HEIGHT = 800;

private Game game = new Game();

public GameGraphics() {
    setTitle("SwitchElements");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);

    drawBoard();
}

private void drawBoard(){
    // 0xF1E4CB
    BoardGraphics board = new BoardGraphics(game.getGameBoard());
    System.out.println((WIDTH-BoardGraphics.WIDTH)/2);
    board.setLocation( (HEIGHT-BoardGraphics.HEIGHT)/2, (WIDTH-BoardGraphics.WIDTH)/2);

    this.add( board );

    this.repaint();
}
}
```

the thing is that I tried everything. But jButtons doesn't stack according to grid.
it seems that all of them adds into one place

Comment: Again, please answer the question of what `Board` is. If it is not a container, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: board is a container for elements.

Comment: Then go over my answer to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "But jButtons doesnt stack according to grid. it seems that all of them adds into one place"

Since you never answered my question/comment asking what `Board` is, I'll make an assumption. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Look at your `GridLayout` construction

```
new GridLayout(board.getHeight(), board.getWidth(), 0, 0)
```

**Assuming `Board` is some kind of container**, let's say of dimension 300, 300.

With your `GridLayout` constructor, you're saying that there should be 300 rows and 300 columns. There's only four iterations total in both your loops, so you only have 4 buttons. The layout is mapped to 9000 available spaces. So yes, all your buttons will only be placed in the top left of the grid (the first four) position, and the rest of the 8996 empty spaces will be an empty space the size of the largest button.

---

What you *can* do to see the buttons add correctly to the grid is pass a couple arguments to your `drawElements()` method to ensure the iterations are the same as the layout params.

```
private void drawElements(int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    ....
}
```

Then call it like

```
public public BoardGraphics(Board board){

    int rows = ...
    int cols = ...
    setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, 0, 0));
    drawElements(rows, cols);
```

---

Also you should avoid using `setSize()` and `setLocation()` for your components. You should be using layout managers and let *them* do the sizing and locating *for* you. You can read [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to learn more about the different layouts available.

Comment: when i'm creating new gridLayout board is ( 8 by 8 ).
also without setSize my buttons doesnt show up at all

Comment: Print out `board.getWidth()` and `board.getHeight()` to see what it returns.

Comment: Also you say you want a grid 8 by 8 but you are only adding 4 buttons. What's that about?

Comment: width: 10, height: 10

Comment: So you have a grid of 100 spaces but you only add 4 buttons.

Comment: ok i did loop for (...;board.getWidth();...) and etc. but i doesnt draw my elements at all

Comment: if i set size then i draws them in one place ( i think )

Comment: 1) Don't set the size to your panel. 2) The frame that is containing the panel, dont set the size, just `pack()` it. 3) Don't set the size of the buttons. See what happens. Using, board.getWidth() and getHeight() for the loops.

Comment: i got a window as small as possible

Comment: Did you `pack()` the frame?

Comment: oh wait something come up :o, i was packing before adding board

Comment: Also not really sure how your code works, but you may want to call `drawBoard()` before `pack()`